# What determines the kind of Bravais lattice structure (body-centred cubic, hexagonal, etc) a transition metal shows?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, periodic-trends, crystallography, bravais-lattices

With the exception of Zn, Hg, Cd and Mn transition metals most transition metals have only one kind of lattice structure at room temperature. Another trend I noticed was that Groups 3 and 4 have hexagonal close packing; 5 and 6 have Body-centred cubic cells; Groups 7 and 8 (with the exception of Iron) have hexagonal close packing; and the last 3 groups have cubic close packing.

Even at higher temperatures, Groups 3 and 4 usually show usually show body-centred cubic packing (Lanthanum is an exception).

I know that in ionic compounds, we can find the type of packing by comparing the ratio of radi, is something like this going on here? But if that were the case the radi and thus the structure would drastically change down the group (which is not happening); so it must have something to do with the electronic configuration. Can someone help, thanks.

Comment: "we can find the type of packing by comparing the ratio of radioactive" ???

Comment: All elements show one structure at STP. What are you asking?

Comment: @JonCuster edited the question to make it clearer

Comment: There is no simple answer. If you think you have one, you are wrong.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, I don't expect a simple answer, but I'm in high school so I would prefer something I can understand

Comment: That's what would constitute a simple answer.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, I'm fine with a complex one too, but I would prefer someone tell me where I can read about those underlying concepts in detail (like some kind of book or a link). Currently I don't even know about the existence of those concepts, forget about understanding them.

Comment: I can't comment as I don't have enough rep but these links may help https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Book%3A_Introduction_to_Inorganic_Chemistry/06%3A_Metals_and_Alloys-_Structure_Bonding_Electronic_and_Magnetic_Properties/6.04%3A_Crystal_Structures_of_Metals https://opentextbc.ca/chemistry/chapter/10-6-lattice-structures-in-crystalline-solids/

Comment: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Band-structure-theory-of-the-bcc-to-hcp-Burgers-Feng-Widom/178c70dd1e390c508c6f553583dd5302e06b865a might be of interest

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1578/5. Also these: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/search?q=bravais